# Is there a way in R to separate sentences where whitespace is missing, i.e. "Sentence one.Sentence two"?

Tags: r, regex, stringr, text-parsing

I've scraped chunks of text from XML files that are often missing whitespace between sentences.  I've used `str_split` with great success to break the chunks into digestible sentences, like below:

```r
list_of_strings <- str_split(chunk_of_text, pattern=boundary("sentence")
```

This works pretty well, but it can't deal with situations where the terminal period is not followed by a space.  For example, `"This sentence ends.This sentence continues."`  It returns this as 1 sentence, not two.

Using `str_split` with `pattern=boundary("sentence")` doesn't work.

If I search and replace periods with period-space, of course that screws up numbers like 1.5 pounds.

I've explored using wildcards to detect the situation, e.g.,

```r
str_view_all(x, "[[:alpha:]]\\.[[:alpha:]]"))
```

but I can't figure out how to either 1) insert a space after the period so a subsequent call to str_split works correctly, or 2) split at the period.

Any advice on separating sentences when this occurs?

Newbie R programmer here, thanks for your help!

Comment: The answer posted is good but also it notes these kind of fixes always struggle with edge cases. Is there a step upstream that you can do to avoid this predicament? It may be the answer is no, if the raw data is informal text, but also your problem can occur if e.g. inner text is stripped from enclosing tags and concatenated into one big string, losing paragraph formatting.

Comment: HI @SamR - yes, the inner text was stripped of enclosing tags and concatenated.  Not sure I can fix that upstream, but good point for me to explore that further!  Thanks!

Comment: Did the concatenation cause the issue? Can you replace it with something like `paste(c("sentence one.", "sentence two."), collapse=" ")`?

Comment: The concatenation came from using xml_read() on large chunks of code.  This stripped out all of the visual whitespace that wasn't actually represented by spaces, tabs, etc.  The XML files are large, complex, and not consistent, so we're grabbing large sections, breaking into sentences, then searching for keywords of interest.  It's not pretty.  There is probably a way to traverse the XML and pull out sentences at a time and throw them into a list or concatenate them with spacing, but I'm at the edge of my knowledge right now to be honest!

Comment: I have regretted taking the quick route in similar situations in the past. But not always. XML is a nightmare and you can judge the time investment trade-off.  If it's simply a question of knowledge you could post a question about XML parsing. I don't think it's near the top of the list of skills that are worth investing in developing these days though.

Comment: I am just learning the joys of XML (sarcasm alert) and this will probably be my last effort with it, so not sure how much I want to invest.  But thanks for the advice about a separate XML parsing post - I might go there for completeness.

Answer (score 5):

```
library(stringr)

x <- "This sentence ends.This sentence continues. It costs 1.5 pounds.They needed it A.S.A.P.Here's one more sentence."

str_split(x, "\\.\\s?(?=[A-Z][^\\.])")
```

```
[[1]]
[1] "This sentence ends"        "This sentence continues"  
[3] "It costs 1.5 pounds"       "They needed it A.S.A.P"   
[5] "Here's one more sentence."
```

Explanation:

```
"\\.                     # literal period
    \\s?                 # optional whitespace
        (?=[A-Z]         # followed by a capital letter 
                [^\\.])" # which isn’t followed by another period
```

Also note this doesn’t account for every possibility. For instance, it’ll erroneously split after `"Dr."` for `"Dr. Perez is on call."`. You could handle that case by adding a negative lookbehind:

```
"(?<!Dr|Mr|Mrs|Ms|Mx)\\.\\s?(?=[A-Z][^\\.])"
```

But the specific contents, and other edge cases to handle, will depend on your data.

Comment: I shouldn't have spent time editing the question, you beat me by a minute ;-)

Comment: Hi @zephryl - thanks for the detailed response.  I can confirm that this snippet does work for the sentences delimited only by periods.  But this dataset has a number of corner cases (it was gotten from an xml_read() so lots of concatenation of text) and it misses many sentences breaks that the boundary("sentence") catches.  I think I need a solution that leverages the boundary("sentence") method by somehow detecting the situation ahead of time.  But thanks for spelling out the regex - very helpful for my learning. Thanks!

Comment: Might be simpler just to  replace every "." with  ".[space]"  and follow that by replacing [2 spaces]  with [one space].      But same cautions about other uses of a "."  apply

Comment: Hi @CarlWitthoft - thanks for the thought.  I tried that at first and it worked but it also broke sentences were numbers appeared, like 1.2 pounds.  I would be fine with extra whitespace if I could also protect numbers.  I would love to use a regex like suggested above to find-and-replace the period and THEN split the sentences.  Thanks for commenting!